# How to install Python's package for Jira REST API

Tags: python, pip

I need to interract with Jira progammatically so I find some Python API. By searching, I found [the REST API](https://pypi.org/project/jira/).
To install it, I executed:
`python setup.py easy_install`

Then the error is:

```
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/sphinx/: Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'sphinx' (maybe misspelled?)
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for sphinx>=1.6.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    pbr=True)
  File "C:\Python27_64bit\lib\distutils\core.py", line 112, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 239, in __init__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 263, in fetch_build_eggs
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 559, in resolve
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 797, in best_match
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 809, in obtain
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_egg
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 587, in easy_install
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('sphinx>=1.6.5')
```

I see the error message mentioned sphinx so I downloaded Sphinx-3.5.4, then installed it, the error now:

```
python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    import sphinx
  File "D:\download\Sphinx-3.5.4.tar\Sphinx-3.5.4\Sphinx-3.5.4\sphinx\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .deprecation import RemovedInNextVersionWarning
  File "D:\download\Sphinx-3.5.4.tar\Sphinx-3.5.4\Sphinx-3.5.4\sphinx\deprecation.py", line 36
    def deprecated_alias(modname: str, objects: Dict[str, object],
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

May I use Sphinx-3.5.4 or sphinx 1.6.5 (it requires sphinx>=1.6.5)?
May I have some of your advice? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `pip install jira ? ` https://pypi.org/project/jira/. Where did you run your `python setup.py easy_install ` ? From source of jira ?

Comment: ` I downloaded Sphinx-3.5.4, then installed it` that is strange, there isn't 2 steps, to get sphinx, you just do `pip install sphinx`. You don't need to download all package you need then install them from source each time. There is `pip` https://pypi.org/project/pip/ the pytohn package installer

Comment: @azro I ran`python setup.py easy_install` from the jira package in which the setup.py file is located.

Comment: So I said, DON'T download packages sources and file. JUST run `pip install XXX` that' is how you install packages in python